# react-select dropdown not showing cursor

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a `react-select` `Select` component that renders a searchable dropdown menu.

Here is a Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-paper-eb4lr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

For some reason, I can't seem to get the cursor to display. The search functionality works fine. I can type in the field but the cursor does not display at all. When looking at the example snippets on the website, the cursor shows appropriately.

In my code, I have a blue dropdown background with white text. I also made the cursor white in the styles object.

```
<Select
    value={currentValue}
    placeholder="N/A"
    components={{ IndicatorSeparator: () => null }}
    onChange={(val: any) => { // do stuff }}
    isSearchable={true}
    autoBlur={true}
    openMenuOnFocus={true}
    options={options}
    styles={getStyles()}
/>
```

**getStyles():**

```
{
    control: (provided: any, state: any) => ({
        ...provided,
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        fontSize: '1rem',
        width: '250px',
        borderRadius: '0px',
        borderStyle: 'none',
        padding: '0 0.5rem 0 0.5rem',
        cursor: 'text',
    }),
    option: (provided: any, state: any) => ({
        ...provided,
        fontWeight: '400',
        color: 'black',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        fontSize: '1rem',
        padding: '0.25rem 0.5rem 0.25rem 0.5rem',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        '&:hover': { backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5' },
    }),
    menu: (provided: any, state: any) => ({
        ...provided,
        fontWeight: '400',
        color: MEDICAL_BLUE,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        fontSize: '1rem',
        padding: '0.25rem 0.5rem 0.25rem 0.5rem',
        borderRadius: '0px',
        borderStyle: 'none',
    }),
    singleValue: (provided: any, state: any) => ({
        ...provided,
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: MEDICAL_BLUE,
        fontSize: '1rem',
    }),
    input: (provided: any, state: any) => {
        return {
            ...provided,
            color: 'white',
        };
    },
    placeholder: (provided: any, state: any) => {
        return {
            ...provided,
            color: 'white',
        };
    },
    dropdownIndicator: (provided: any, state: any) => {
        return {
            ...provided,
            color: 'white',
            '&:hover': { color: '#F5F5F5' },
        };
    },
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is a Sandbox showing the behavior I'm seeing. As you can see, without anything selected, I can see the cursor when clicking in the dropdown. However, once I select a value, clicking on the menu again shows no cursor.

[image: Edit lingering-paper-eb4lr]

Comment: it looks like it should work, might be a caching issue; try ctrl+f5. are you able to create a sandbox to replicate the issue?

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 Yes, I edited the original post to include a Sandbox

Comment: the sandbox works for me, I can see the cursor, I'm using G chrome on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my own issue, so I'm writing this to help out future souls.

Turns out that the `singleValue` style key styles the selected value for the dropdown input which removes any cursor. I haven't discovered any way to workaround it but removing the `singleValue` style key and re-styling my dropdown to have a white background instead of a dark blue background worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the main issue is because of the background color of the value selected on the dropdown. In fact, if you give it `transparent` as value, it works. It's probably covering the cursor. Primarily addressing the OP that you can still retain the background color of blue for your dropdown but just remove the background color of the value selected

```
singleValue: (provided: any, state: any) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: "white",
    // backgroundColor: "#004080", // comment this out
    fontSize: "1rem"
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

For whom this may help, I had also no cursor appearing on the select input.

More specifically:

- The input had a placeholder
- When the input had not yet any text but it was focused, NO cursor was appearing.
- When typing any text, the cursor appeared.
- Removing any text the cursor was still there.

So inspecting the input field (selector is  .react-select__input) I noticed that it had min-width of 3px. But the actual width was less that 3px. Typing text would increase the width.

The solution I found, it was simply to add a margin-left.

```
.react-select__input {
   margin-left: 1px !important;
}
```

So in my case it was not related to color styling, but that the input field was initially without enough width to show the cursor. That explained why after typing any text I could see the cursor again.